# How can I control my led strip on my Linux server via bluetooth?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, controls, strip, led

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server on a laptop that has bluetooth adapter. I also have a led strip from China which also has a bluetooth adapter. I can control my led through an app on my phone.

Is there any way to successfully connect to the led strip with my linux laptop and control it?
If so, how could I know which code / key (or I don't know how this bluetooth control works, sorry) is assigned to a color? So basically, I don't know what command should I send to the strip.

Can anybody please write an example program for me?

I tried the rfcomm, bluetoothctl and bluetooth-sendto but they didn't work. :(

Hope we can solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to reverse engineer your device :

with little research I found this

http://nilhcem.com/iot/reverse-engineering-simple-bluetooth-devices